# way to use tomcat basic/digest authentication with hashed passwords in JDBCRealm?

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, jdbc, jdbcrealm

I want to use Tomcats role based authentication, problem is i'm storing the passwords hashed in my database so cannot use basic authentication/or digest. Is there a way to compare the clear text password with the hashed password? I'm usng SHA to hash passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat can hash the user's attempted password and compare it to what you have in the database. This won't work with `HTTP DIGEST` but it should work with `HTTP BASIC`. You probably want to use `DataSourceRealm` and not `JDBCRealm` because it will perform much better.

Just configure your `<Realm>` like this:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
  dataSourceName="jdbc/myDataSource"
       userTable="users"
     userNameCol="user_name"
     userCredCol="user_pass"
   userRoleTable="user_roles"
     roleNameCol="role_name"
          digest="SHA1" />
```

Obviously, you'll have to customize the values above to match what you have in your database.

A bit of a note: SHA1 hashing is not sufficient to protect a stored credential from being reverse-engineered if your user database is stolen. You will need to implement some kind of password-strengthening strategy to protect your users' credentials. I would recommend trying to shift from SHA1 over to something like PBKDF2, bcrypt/scrypt, or even using SHA-512 with a salt and a non-trivial number of iterations (like many thousands). Recent versions of Tomcat can handle iterations and salting for you, and also allow you to plug-in other functions such as bcrypt/scrypt and PBKDF2 fairly easily.